# Crystal Reports - how to pass parameter?

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to pass a parameter to my report and put the report into my project.

I want to pass a user id as parameter to the report.

The id will be different each time.

Can someone help me on this topic how to pass the parameter.

Here is my code so far:

```
CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = True
Dim rDoc As New ReportDocument()

' Crystal Report Name
rDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("Sucess.rpt"))
' Your .rpt file path

'set dataset to the report viewer.
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rDoc
```

Comment: yes i know that but what i want is to pass a parameter to the crystalreportviewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
    string ponumber;
    string receiptno;

    ponumber = TextBox1.Text;      

    CrystalReportSource CrystalReportSource1 = new CrystalReportSource();
    CrystalReportViewer CrystalReportViewer1 = new CrystalReportViewer();

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CrystalReportSource1;
    CrystalReportViewer1.EnableParameterPrompt = false;
    CrystalReportSource1.Report.FileName = "Report3.rpt";
    CrystalReportSource1.EnableCaching = false;

    CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(0, ponumber);
    CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue(1, receiptno);
```